# Set language settings in cookie from click of a link

Tags: php, url, cookies, setcookie

Hi I have HTML like this

```
    <div class="header_countrys_middle">    
    <a href="http://www.test.com" title="United States"><img src="/images/flags/us.gif" alt="us" title="United States" /></a>
</div>
```

I set the language like this:

```
setcookie("lang", "en_US");
```

But how do I set the language based on users click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could be lazy and use:

```
 <a onClick="javascript:document.cookie='lang=en_US'"><img src=flags...>
```

Or use a server-side script:

```
 <a href="setlang.php?lang=en_US"> ..
```

With setlang.php being

```
 <?php
    setcookie("lang", urlencode($_GET["lang"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set an onclick event (and an ID to anchor element in order to select it easily)

```
<div class="header_countrys_middle">    
  <a href="http://www.test.com" id="lang" title="United States"><img src="/images/flags/us.gif" alt="us" title="United States" /></a>
</div>

document.getElementById('lang').onclick = function(){
  // this happens before the page changes
  setcookie('lang', 'en_US');
});
```